# TNS-connection closed error while updating oracle tables from Informatica powercenter

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter, tns

I often get below error while running some sessions in Informatica Powercenter. The session is supposed to insert/update some records in oracle tables.

```
Username USER123 DB Error -1
Database driver Error...
Function Name: Logon
ORA-12537: TNS-connection closed
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [USER123] and connection string [ORCL123]
```

This is totally random. I have ran the same sessions sometimes smoothly without a singe hitch. But sometimes the error comes back again and again. Whenever it occurs, stays for 5 mins max, means if I restart the session immediately after failure, it will fail again. But if I wait for 5 mins and restart them again, it runs successfully. But the only problem is it comes back again in another half an hour or so.

Can somebody enlighten me to get a probable resolution for the error?

Answer (score 1):

Do check the number of connections allowed on the Oracle instance if they are exceeding intermittently by other users and refusing your user connection from Informatica.